# How many words can we make with the following letters $PTEXYPADFYOLNQYIG$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, combinatorics-on-words

How do you solve this? How many words can we make with the following letters  PTEXYPADFYOLNQYIG keeping the vowels in the same position?

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far ? 2. Can the  vowels be interchanged while the  *group* of vowels occupy the same positions ?

Comment: 1. Count the vowels and consonants (4 and 10 different cases ) and 2. Permute 2 different cases, consonant and letters can repeat keeping the position , like 10*10*4*10*10*10*4… or use all the letters (4 vowels and 13 consonants) to permute while every char is different, like 13*12*4*11*10*9*3…. What do you think?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. With vowels retaining their position, but permutable, they can be placed in $4!$ ways
2. There are $13$ consonants including $2 P's$ and $3 Y's$ which necessarily have to remain in the places for consonants, so permute in $\dfrac{13!}{2!3!}$ ways
3. Multiply the two to get total possible arrangements with given restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I was so wrong then

Comment: You are welcome, but do brush up on fundamental concepts !

Comment: Thank you, any advice for beginners ? Sometimes I don’t see clearly the logic behind combinatorics problem :(

Comment: Get an introductory book with a lot of worked examples, eg Schaum series